# adding zoom breaks the menu scrolling functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a landing page with a menu that scrolls you to the section selected. However my client pointed out that he liked the page with a 90% zoom. I  decided to add the following line:

```
body {
   zoom:90%;
}
```

Whenever I click a menu option, I get scrolled down past the section I clicked. Is there a way to keep both the zoom and the scrolling functionality?

Here is the page I'm working with in which you can see the problem by yourself:

http://soldaforte.com/

Comment: I would recommend building the site at 100% zoom regardless of what your client says. Your client has the option to set the zoom on his/her browser

Comment: You are aware of the fact that this does not work in Firefox? And I think that its a bad idea to use this attribute at all and if only because of that fact. Better go ahead and adapt your CSS as a whole and do not use such tricks.

Comment: You should recommend against this method as it is a non-standard technique https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/zoom/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the browser compatibility for this website is bad - and that's being generous. To be fair this is more of a logic problem. You've set the height of each section, and you've set a scroll amount. So it's no surprise that when you zoom out you are going to need a different scroll amount and height for each section. To fix this, add padding to each section to fill the height of the screen, then scroll by the new section height.

Personally, I think you're better off changing the sizes of everything to 90% of it's current size: redesign what you have instead of trying to cover up mistakes. If your client likes 90%, make it 90% instead of making it appear to be 90%.

**Note:** would have been a comment but ranted on a bit...